# How to customize edit event in JsGrid

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jsgrid

I'm using [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com) and want to know if it's possible how to customize `onclick` event of `editButton`. Basically, doing something like displaying modal instead of inline editing. I know that we can get the HTML output of control column like this :

```
{
    type: 'control',
    itemTemplate: function() {
        var $result = jsGrid.fields.control.prototype.itemTemplate.apply(this, arguments); // Array of string
        return $result;
    }
}
```

But how to have control on `EditButton`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
editItem: function(item) {
  var $row = this.rowByItem(item);
  if ($row.length) {
    console.log('$row: ' + JSON.stringify($row)); // I modify this
    this._editRow($row);
  }
},
```

at your jsGrid config.

All lines except line `// I modify this` are default from original source of jsGrid, so dont change them.

Comment: `$("#jsgrd").jsGrid({
        data: ds,
        fields: [{ type: "control",editItem: editrow(item)}, `  -- Tried like this to define function `editrow` outside of the jsgrid definition. got error item not defined. is this not right?